# Detecting a table in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

Im fairly new to image processing so I was looking for some help on where to start or some input on how to do this if you know the answer.

What I would like to be able to do is take an image with a table in it, and be able to detect the table. Id even be happy to settle with detecting many planar surfaces as I can sift through that part easily. What I get right now with openCV when I do some contour detection is:
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D2wq.jpg),
[Contour Detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btOof.jpg)

As  you can see this may have potential with some sophistication maybe, but it missed the bulk of the table. Im currently working in Python for this as well.

Comment: i would guess that you will need to identify some characteristics of an image and use that as inputs to ANN .... it can probably get pretty good accuracy with sufficient training ... this might provide a starting place https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-3-deep-learning-and-convolutional-neural-networks-f40359318721#.l7jsgqvmb

Comment: you could also just use an existing image classification service like https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: if you are new to image processing, start with something simple. you won't have much fun if you lack the basics

Comment: I agree with @Piglet, but if you are trying to detect planar surfaces maybe I'd starting thinking about 3D sensing (stereoscopy, Structured light, etc). It is much easier to detect planar surfaces in 3D data.